# Vaadin TreeTable: How to update an item?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Vaadin 7 `TreeTable`, which I fill with some items at the start of the application.

Then, the user can select a particular item, click on it and modify it.

How can I

1. modify the data (property values) of that particular item and
2. make `TreeTable` update (redraw) it so that the changes become visible to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the data binding API of Vaadin the changes are automatically updated to browser. Here's a simple example of updating the value of a property:

```
treeTable.getContainerProperty(itemId, "propertyid").setValue("newvalue");
```

Comment: Like Henri said, this is automatically done if you bind your components to the data. One of the simplest ways is to use item containers: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html